# Quartz.net Configure several jobs in XML

Tags: c#, xml, jobs, quartz.net, job-scheduling

How to configure correctly the XML for several jobs in Quartz.Net? Is there any tutorials on that?
I found tutorials for one job in the XML. It is working. But I am not sure for several jobs how to configure the quartz_jobs.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you that a "jobs" (plural) xml-tag would be more intuitive. But basically you put in multiple "job" (singular) xml elements.  And just ignore the fact there is no `<jobs>` (plural) element.

Note that the

```
<job><name>
```

needs to match the

```
<trigger><simple><job-name>
```

value, to get the job to map to the correct trigger.

But here is my xml for 2 jobs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">


    <!-- This value wipes out existing jobs...be very careful with it being "true"  -->
    <processing-directives>
        <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
    </processing-directives>

    <schedule>

<!-- First Job -->

        <job>
            <name>LogStuffJobJobName</name>
            <group>LogStuffJobGroupName</group>
            <description>LogStuffJobNonConcurrentJob Description</description>
            <job-type>MyCompany.Apps.QuartzPOC.BAL.Jobs.LogStuffJobNonConcurrentJob, MyCompany.Apps.QuartzPOC.BAL</job-type>
            <durable>true</durable>
            <recover>false</recover>
            <job-data-map>
                <!--Parameters for the job-->
                <entry>
                    <key>JobDetailParameter001</key>
                    <value>Value001_Set_In_Quartz_Jobs_001_xml</value>
                </entry>


                <entry>
                    <key>DefinedInJobDetailAndTriggerKey</key>
                    <value>DefinedInJobDetailAndTriggerKeyValue_JobElement_Set_In_Quartz_Jobs_001_xml</value>
                </entry>

            </job-data-map>
        </job>
        <trigger>

            <simple>
                <name>LogStuffJobTriggerName</name>
                <group>LogStuffJobTriggerGroup</group>
                <description>LogStuffJobTriggerName Description</description>
                <job-name>LogStuffJobJobName</job-name>
                <job-group>LogStuffJobGroupName</job-group>


                <job-data-map>
                    <entry>
                        <key>TriggerParameter001Key</key>
                        <value>TriggerParameter001Value_Set_In_Quartz_Jobs_001_xml</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>TriggerParameter002Key</key>
                        <value>TriggerParameter002Value_Set_In_Quartz_Jobs_001_xml</value>
                    </entry>

                    <entry>
                        <key>DefinedInJobDetailAndTriggerKey</key>
                        <value>DefinedInJobDetailAndTriggerKeyValue_TriggerElement_Set_In_Quartz_Jobs_001_xml</value>
                    </entry>                    

                </job-data-map>

                <!--<start-time>1982-06-28T18:15:00.0Z</start-time>-->
                <!--<end-time>2020-05-04T18:13:51.0Z</end-time>-->
                <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
                <!-- repeat indefinitely every 5 seconds -->
                <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
                <repeat-interval>5000</repeat-interval>



            </simple>

        </trigger>


    <!-- Second Job -->
        <job>
            <name>TextFilePoppingJobJobName</name>
            <group>TextFilePoppingJobGroupName</group>
            <description>TextFilePoppingJob Desription</description>
            <job-type>MyCompany.Apps.QuartzPOC.BAL.Jobs.TextFilePoppingJob, MyCompany.Apps.QuartzPOC.BAL</job-type>
            <durable>true</durable>
            <recover>false</recover>
            <job-data-map>
                <entry>
                    <key>FavoriteActor</key>
                    <value>Harrison Ford</value>
                </entry>

                <entry>
                    <key>FavoriteColor</key>
                    <value>Green</value>
                </entry>
            </job-data-map>
        </job>



        <trigger>

            <simple>
                <name>TextFilePoppingJobTriggerName</name>
                <group>TextFilePoppingJobTriggerGroup</group>
                <description>TextFilePoppingJobTriggerName Description</description>
                <job-name>TextFilePoppingJobJobName</job-name>
                <job-group>TextFilePoppingJobGroupName</job-group>


                <job-data-map>
                    <entry>
                        <key>FavoriteCity</key>
                        <value>Chicago</value>
                    </entry>

                </job-data-map>

                <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
                <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
                <repeat-interval>10000</repeat-interval>

            </simple>

        </trigger>



    </schedule>



</job-scheduling-data>
```